# R implemantion and optimization of a function

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

I have a function that I need to implement in R

```
L = Σ i=1->n  ( 1/β* e^(((µ-yi))/β) - e^(-e^((µ-yi)/β) ))
```

And then I have to use a optimisation function in R to find the value of `µ` and `β` that maximise  this
function.

The data of `y` are given.

```
           Y
1   5.539341
2   2.607342
3   2.675443
4   2.905286
5   3.657362
6   5.175831
7   3.830794
8   2.664615
9   5.741146
10  4.432348
11  3.326155
12  2.637661
13  3.306147
14  2.840939
15  3.559279
```

I thought about

```
vraislogn <-
    function (p,y){
    logvrais=log(L)
    β=p[2]
    µ=p[1]
    return(-logvrais)}`
nlm(vraislogn,p=c(1,1),y=y)
```

when I change p =c(1,1) to for example p=c(2,3) I have a difference in the estimated value and the minimum function that I found is negatif what is absurd!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why do find negative values absurd? Your function can become negative. It can even reach negative values of very large magnitudes. A sensitivity to starting values is to be expected if local minima exist.

```
y <- unlist(read.table(text="           Y
1   5.539341
2   2.607342
3   2.675443
4   2.905286
5   3.657362
6   5.175831
7   3.830794
8   2.664615
9   5.741146
10  4.432348
11  3.326155
12  2.637661
13  3.306147
14  2.840939
15  3.559279"))

L <- function(p, y) {
  sum(1 / p[1] * exp((p[2] - y)/p[1]) - exp(-exp((p[2] - y)/p[1])))
}

library(optimx)
optimx(par = c(1, 1), L, y=y, method=c( 'Nelder-Mead', 'BFGS', 'CG', 'L-BFGS-B', 'nlm', 
          'nlminb', 'spg', 'ucminf', 'newuoa', 'bobyqa', 'nmkb', 'hjkb', 'Rcgmin'))
#                       p1            p2          value fevals gevals niter convcode  kkt1  kkt2 xtimes
#Nelder-Mead -6.424696e-03  1.213437e+00 -1.797693e+308    359     NA    NA        0    NA    NA   0.00
#BFGS        -2.688898e-02 -6.893257e+00 -4.304276e+205    413      5    NA        0 FALSE FALSE   0.02
#CG          -2.164624e+06 -1.457184e+06  -2.111903e+00    200    101    NA        1  TRUE FALSE   0.00
#L-BFGS-B     1.020495e-01  4.385857e-01  -1.500000e+01     13     13    NA        0  TRUE FALSE   0.00
#nlm         -1.282396e-02 -1.191648e+00 -4.752890e+236     NA     NA     6        0 FALSE FALSE   0.00
#nlminb       8.706765e-02  5.051164e-01  -1.500000e+01     16     57    15        0  TRUE FALSE   0.00
#spg          1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  -1.201022e+01      1     NA     1        3 FALSE FALSE   0.04
#ucminf      -5.526900e-03  2.211903e+00 -3.797103e+279     20     20    NA        0 FALSE    NA   0.00
#newuoa                 NA            NA  8.988466e+307     NA     NA    NA     9999    NA    NA   0.00
#bobyqa       4.812801e-02  7.576366e-01  -1.500000e+01    121     NA    NA        0  TRUE  TRUE   0.00
#nmkb                   NA            NA  8.988466e+307     NA     NA    NA     9999    NA    NA   0.00
#hjkb         1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  -1.201022e+01      1     NA     0     9999    NA    NA   0.00
#Rcgmin                 NA            NA  8.988466e+307     NA     NA    NA     9999    NA    NA   0.00
```

Let's constrain the parameters to positive values:

```
optimx(par = c(1, 1), L, y=y, 
       method=c( 'L-BFGS-B', 'nlminb', 'bobyqa'),
       lower=c(0,0))
#                 p1        p2 value fevals gevals niter convcode kkt1  kkt2 xtimes
#L-BFGS-B 0.11115122 0.2651588   -15     16     16    NA        0 TRUE FALSE      0
#nlminb   0.08866507 0.5038754   -15     15     54    14        0 TRUE FALSE      0
#bobyqa   0.05325943 0.7253612   -15    117     NA    NA        0 TRUE FALSE      0
```

Nope. The minimum is still negative. Could there be a mistake in your function?

Comment: I did find an answer when I withdraw the sum from the function.